# how to make a 2 level array to asimple array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
[12601] => Array (
        ['docUpload'] => html dom.txt
)

[12602] => Array (
        ['docUpload'] => PYTHON AND DJANGO ARE HUGE IN FINTECH.txt
)
[12603] => Array (
        ['docUpload'] => 
)
```

How to get it like this:

```
12601 => html dom.txt
12602 => PYTHON AND DJANGO ARE HUGE IN FINTECH.txt
```

can you help me please?

Comment: `foreach` loop? p.s. can you clean up your formatting please, it's not clear what we're looking at.

Comment: yes with a foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

Use  `array_column()` to get the values, then combine them with `array_combine()`  and `array_keys()`.

```php
$values = array_column($array, 'docUpload');
$newArray = array_combine(array_keys($array), $values);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/lG4KO

Comment: Will it filter empty string? maybe add `array_filter` after the `array_combine`

Comment: This does not do any filtration, no. If OP wants to filter empty strings, then yes, you just add `array_filter()` to `$newArray`.

Comment: I know - but that what the OP post in his desire output... (I just recommend add that in your post)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the array by `foreach()`

**Steps:**

1) Take a new blank array. We are appending our results into this.

2) If the array is not empty, loop over the array by `foreach`

3) Use key value pairs. Key is the `id` in required array.

4) Value is an array with key `docUpload` to be the document name.

5) Append new element with `id` and `value` (`docUpload`).

6) Resulting array will be a single dimensional array.

**Final Code:**

```
$arr = [];
$arr[12401] = ['docUpload' => ''];
$arr[12601] = ['docUpload' => 'html dom.txt'];
$arr[12602] = ['docUpload' => 'PYTHON AND DJANGO ARE HUGE IN FINTECH.txt'];
$arr[12603] = ['docUpload' => ''];
$newArr = [];
if (! empty($arr)) {
 foreach ($arr as $id => $docArr) {
  $newArr[$id] = $docArr['docUpload'];
 }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($newArr);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [12401] => 
    [12601] => html dom.txt
    [12602] => PYTHON AND DJANGO ARE HUGE IN FINTECH.txt
    [12603] => 
)
```

[Working Link:](https://3v4l.org/A1UHS)

Comment: it s a dynamic array..so i vcant use fixed id like u suggested.

Comment: i get the array from a foreach loop....like such foreach($_FILES['docUpload']["name"] AS $key=>$file) {
    The array i provided above in the code is the $file

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to do as follows:

```
foreach ($arrayData as &$value) {
    $value = isset($value['docUpload']) ? $value['docUpload'] : '';
}
```

It will result in following array:

```
[docUpload] => [
    [12601] => html dom.txt
    [12602] => PYTHON AND DJANGO ARE HUGE IN FINTECH.txt
];
```

Comment: i get this Notice: Undefined index: docUpload in

Comment: I have updated answer. Please try now.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: no, it isnt..i changed the whole interface so that i dont have to go this way. Thanks anyway